# Using aggregate $lookup and $mergeObjects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to join collection.
before, I used only lookup, so that I could get separated field that is joined.
but I need to get result similar mysql join.
I noticed there is $lookup and $mergeObjects for this action but not working well.

user collection model.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "name": 'admin user',
    "email": 'admin@test.com',
    "password": 'xxxxxxxx',
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "approved": true
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "name": 'userOne',
    "email": 'user@test.com',
    "password": 'xxxxxxxx',
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
}
```

roles collection model.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "id": '0',
    "name": 'administrator'
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "id": '0',
    "name": 'employeer'
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "id": '0',
    "name": 'freelancer'
}
```

after join, I want to get result like below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "name": 'admin user',
    "email": 'admin@test.com',
    "password": 'xxxxxxxx',
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "administrator",    //join result
            "approved": true
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "freelancer",       //join result
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), //this is default id from mongoDB
    "name": 'userOne',
    "email": 'user@test.com',
    "password": 'xxxxxxxx',
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "employeer",        //join result
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xZ4CLVIhdK3) with mongodb **3.4**

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the roles array first and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rollback again

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$roles" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "roles",
    "localField": "roles.id",
    "foreignField": "id",
    "as": "roles.role"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$roles.role" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "roles": { "$mergeObjects": ["$roles.role", "$roles"] }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "email": { "$first": "$email" },
    "password": { "$first": "$password" },
    "roles": { "$push": "$roles" }
  }},
  { "$project": { "roles.role": 0 }}
])
```

Which is quite simple with the mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$roles" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "roles",
    "let": { "roleId": "$roles.id", "approved": "$roles.approved" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$id", "$$roleId"] }}},
      { "$addFields": { "approved": "$$approved" }}
    ],
    "as": "roles"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$roles" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "email": { "$first": "$email" },
    "password": { "$first": "$password" },
    "roles": { "$push": "$roles" }
  }}
])
```

Both will give you similar [**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EJiJa9YtgNd)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "email": "user@test.com",
    "password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "roles": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "approved": true,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "employeer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "email": "admin@test.com",
    "password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "roles": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "approved": true,
        "id": 0,
        "name": "administrator"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "approved": true,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "freelancer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, btw this query makes new field as named "newRoles".
I wanna merge roles and newRoles like above expected result.

Comment: You can keep it as roles as well

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: A more effective way to accomplish this? I am using mongo 4.2.8