# MongoDB add $lookup result to array

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections

users:

```
{
  { _id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Sarah' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Mike' }
}
```

services:

```
{
  { _id: 1, 
    payment: [
      { uid: 1, paid: true },
      { uid: 2, paid: false }
    ]
  },
  { _id: 2, 
    payment: [
      { uid: 3, paid: true }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need result like this (from services):

```
{
  { _id: 1, 
    payment: [
      { uid: 1, paid: true, user: { _id: 1, name: 'John' } },
      { uid: 2, paid: false, user: { _id: 2, name: 'Sarah' } }
    ]
  },
  { _id: 2, 
    payment: [
      { uid: 3, paid: true, user: { _id: 3, name: 'Mike' } }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can $lookup by uid field, but how to add "paid" field to each item in lookup result? I know that it's must be really simple... but not for me now ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to `$unwind` the `payment` and then make `$lookup` then use `$group` to rollback. Something like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421801/mongodb-add-to-joining-collection-field-from-base-one/52422185#52422185), and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630587/using-aggregate-lookup-and-mergeobjects/49631604#49631604)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('services').aggregate([
    { "$match": {} },
    { "$unwind": '$payment' },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "localField": "payment.cid",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "user_data"
    }},
    { "$unwind": '$user_data' },
    { "$addFields": {
        "payment.user.name": "$user_data.name",
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "payment": { "$push": "$payment" }
    }}
])
```